# Inheriting from nested structs: templates and pointers

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, nested-class

I am trying to add some additional fields to a nested struct in C++, and the design dictates that I want to do so via inheritance.  I'm getting an error that curiously depends on whether I'm working with type T* or type T**.  I'm fairly confused and would appreciate somebody helping me to understand what's happening here.

The nested struct is Base::Node, and I want to add a field, b, to Base::Node then use Derived as shown in the main.  When I set the #define at the top to 0, everything compiles and works fine.  When I change the #define to 1, I get the following compiler error:

```
main_inhtest.cpp: In instantiation of ‘Derived<int>’:
main_inhtest.cpp:52:   instantiated from here
main_inhtest.cpp:44: error: conflicting return type specified for ‘Derived<T>::DNode** Derived<T>::GetNAddr() [with T = int]’
main_inhtest.cpp:24: error:   overriding ‘Base<T>::Node** Base<T>::GetNAddr() [with T = int]’
main_inhtest.cpp: In member function ‘Derived<T>::DNode** Derived<T>::GetNAddr() [with T = int]’:
main_inhtest.cpp:57:   instantiated from here
main_inhtest.cpp:44: error: invalid static_cast from type ‘Base<int>::Node**’ to type ‘Derived<int>::DNode**’
```

Could somebody help me understand

1. Whether this is the right way to be doing this, and if there is a better way, and
2. Why the compiler is happy with the GetN() methods but not the GetNAddr() methods?

Thanks!

```
#include <iostream>

#define TRY_GET_N_ADDR 1

template <typename T> class Base {
public:
  Base() { n = new Node(); }

  struct Node
  {
    T a;
  };      
  virtual Node *GetN() { return n; }
  virtual Node **GetNAddr() { return &n; }  

  Node *n;
};

template <typename T> class Derived : public Base<T> {
public:
  Derived() { Base<T>::n = new DNode(); }

  struct DNode : Base<T>::Node
  {
    T b;
  };

  // This method is fine
  DNode *GetN() { return static_cast<DNode *>(Base<T>::GetN()); }

#if TRY_GET_N_ADDR
  // Compiler error here
  DNode **GetNAddr() { return static_cast<DNode **>(Base<T>::GetNAddr()); }
#endif
};

int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {
  Derived<int> d;

  d.GetN()->a = 1;
  d.GetN()->b = 2;

  std::cout << d.GetN()->a << " " << d.GetN()->b << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not with nested structs or templates, but with pointers to pointers and inheritance:

- Base* can hold an instance of Derived*, and so Base* can be down-casted to Derived*.
- Base** can not hold an instance of Derived**, and so can't be down-casted to Derived**.

If Base** could hold an array of Derived's, you could have done the following:

```
Derived* pDerived;
Derived** ppDerived = &pDerived;
Base** ppBase = ppDerived; // not allowed in real world
*ppBase = new Base;        // should be safe, right?
pDerived->derivedFunc();   // invoked on instance of Base!
```

The last line would have resulted in some arbitrary error. Therefore, that kind of assignment is not allowed.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your second question:

If you override a virtual function, the signatures have to match. The only excetion of this rule is that if in the base class the function returns a pointer or a reference to some class `B`, then the overriding method can return pointer or reference to type `D` where `D` is derived from B (this is calles return type covariance). Having said this, it must be clear why your `GetN` works - `DNode` is derived from `Node` and the base class function returns a `Node*` and the overrider returns `DNode*`.

Now let's look at `GetNAddr`. The base class method returns a `Node**` or `pointer to Node*`. You could change this return type in an overriding function in the derived class ***if it were to return something that is derived from Node****. But that is naturally impossible, since a pointer cannot have derived classes. `DNode*` is not derived from `Node*` - hence the compiler complains

Comment: It would also not make sense to return `DNode**`: The function `Base<T>::GetNAddr()` invariably and immutably returns `&n`, which is always of type `Node**`. There isn't even anything polymorphic going on here.